# Socket.io client-side javascript file location (with nginx reverse proxy)

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to run multiple NodeJS apps on the same server/port, using nginx as a reverse proxy which proxies to the actual running Node app.

```
server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  node.domain.com;
    root         /var/www/node;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    # Enables WS support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    location /irc/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
    }

    location /voidwalker/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8003;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have different projects (NodeJS apps) running (using `forever`) in different subdirectories of `/var/www/node`.

But I want to use [socket.io](http://www.socket.io) in one of my projects. And in the socket.io docs it states that I should use `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>` to load socket.io-client on the client side, which returns a 404:

```
GET http://node.domain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm guessing this is because I'm proxying the requests but I don't entirely understand how that process works internally and I would love to get this to work.

Something to note regarding this is that I have to use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/voidwalker/css/main.css">` to load my CSS, while I would rather use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">` in case I want to deploy it on a specific subdomain/other domain (since this is a development server).

**EDIT**

So, after some debugging together with Ray Stantz we think there is something going wrong in the proxy. I moved socket.io.js into `/public/js/socket.io.js` and I can now use it but this isn't the right solution.

If anyone has any ideas on this, I'll be pleased to hear them and try them out!

Comment: Does http://127.0.0.1:8001/ serve /socket.io/socket.io.js? IE, can you  GET it without the proxy?

Comment: I'm quite new to CentOS/Linux in general. My server is running CentOS 6.5 (CLI), any idea on how I would check this?

Comment: But I'm trying to get socket.io to working on /voidwalker/ (:8003), therefor socket.io should be installed under /voidwalker/node_modules/..., right?

Comment: I think my question was unclear. Here is what I was getting at: If your html page includes socket.io:
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
Then one of your node apps or perhaps nginx itself has to serve it. Where are you trying to serve it from?

Comment: I installed it using `npm install`, which downloads and installs all the dependencies etc. The package.json is located at `/voidwalker/package.json`, and therefore socket.io is installed in `/voidwalker/node_modules/socket.io/...`. I read somewhere that `/socket.io/socket.io.js` is not the actual location of the file, but that socket.io handles that internally.

Comment: What does GET http://node.domain.com/voidwalker/socket.io/socket.io.js return?

Comment: It returns: `Cannot GET /voidwalker/socket.io/socket.io.js`, and node.domain.com/socket.io/socket.io.js returns `Cannot GET /socket.io/socket.io.js`

Comment: On the server where you have socket.io installed can you hit http://localhost:8003/socket.io/socket.io.js?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49425/discussion-between-cas-cornelissen-and-ray-stantz)

Comment: I am facing a similar kind of an issue. Could someone please help me solve: http://serverfault.com/questions/699451/nginx-reverse-proxy-for-apache-and-socket-io-on-a-ssl-enabled-site

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue. Resolved by routing `/socket.io` to my node.js application in the nginx configuration. In your case it should look like:

```
server {
    listen       8000;
    server_name  node.domain.com;
    root         /var/www/node;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    # Enables WS support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_redirect off;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
    }

    location /irc/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8002;
    }

    location /voidwalker/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8003;
    }

    location /socket.io {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8003;
    }
}
```

The only drawback for this solution is that only the `voidwalker` app can use socket.io (since `/socket.io` is served only on 127.0.0.1:8003).